# Process for converting unity asset to scenekit scene/resource

Tags: unity, scenekit

Has anyone successfully figured out a method for converting a unity3d asset to a 3d SceneKit model/scene? I imagine it would require exporting the asset into some third party file type, and then importing into scene kit. If you have any knowledge that can help me, would you kindly explain the process?

Unity3d has a fantastic asset store, and I want to import some of these things to a project that requires scenekit (unfortunately, "just use unity" is not really an answer to my problem-set).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need the Collada exporter which you can find on the Unity Asset Store to convert your models and scenes to .dae format for importing into SceneKit. There is one exporter for Unity 5.x and one for Unity 2017.